# Perl LibXLST failing on Mac OS Big Sur 11.4

Tags: macos, perl, macos-big-sur, libxslt

I'm having trouble with a Perl application that fails with an LibXSLT-related error on Mac OS Big Sur 11.4 on multiple computers (all Intel Macs) - it worked correctly before the Mac OS upgrade, and now seems to fail on a freshly installed up-to date Mac.

The error message for a minimal script `perl -MXML::LibXSLT -E 'say $INC{"XML/LibXSLT.pm"}'` (using system perl - no other perl is installed on the machine) is as follows:

> Can't load '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle' for module XML::LibXSLT: dlopen(/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle, 0x0001): symbol '_xsltLibxsltVersion' not found, expected in flat namespace by '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle' at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
> at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/XML/LibXSLT.pm line 48.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/XML/LibXSLT.pm line 48.
> Compilation failed in require.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

`cpan -i XML::LibXSLT` confirms that `XML::LibXSLT is up to date (1.99).`

I tried updating the xslt libraries with `brew install libxslt` but it did not seem to make any difference.

I've tried running `brew link libxslt --force`, which now does not do anything (`Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: libxslt`).

Running `cpan -f -t XML::LibXSLT` fails with the following error message:

```
looking for -lxslt... no
libxslt not found
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
```

If I set the LIBS and INC values to the path suggested by brew `export LIBS="-L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib"` and `export INC="-I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include"`, it still fails with this error.

Any suggestions on how to debug this? I'm not a Perl developer, just trying to run an existing app.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `cpan -f -t XML::LibXSLT` run successfully?

Comment: The module install fine here. macOS 11.2.3, perlbrew perl version 5.32.0. Are you using the system perl?

Comment: *"Can't load '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle' for module XML::LibXSLT"* : Is this an error you get when running `cpan XML::LibXSLT` or is it coming from a script that uses the module?

Comment: Is this an M1 or an intel Mac?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes, it's using the system perl, nothing else is installed.

Comment: @ikegami it does not, I edited to add the errors regarding this.

Comment: @HåkonHægland also, I believe that this problem wasn't an issue on macOS 11.2.3, it's something specific to recent macOS changes. Everything worked on the same machine before the latest OS upgrade; I have installed and run the same script earlier on multiple computers, on earlier macOS versions it worked without non-system perl or anything else unusual. I don't have any macs available now with an older macOS version to verify, but I replicated this on another clean mac (didn't have anything perl- or xml-related installed ever, only apple devtools) with 11.4 which has the exact same errors.

Comment: I tried with the system perl now. I first installed `cpanm` with `sudo cpan App::cpanminus`, then tried `sudo cpanm XML::LibXSLT` and it failed with `looking for -lxslt... libxslt not found. Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line` But the strange thing is that if I run it again it says `XML::LibXSLT is up to date. (1.99)`. So there might also be a bug in `cpan` and `cpanm` here.. Can you try with perlbrew?

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/issues/628)

Comment: Can you update your question with the minimal script that produces the error? When I uses the system perl (with the preinstalled XML::LibXSLT) the following script for example runs fine here: `perl -MXML::LibXSLT -E 'say $INC{"XML/LibXSLT.pm"}'`. Does this one-liner give you the same error?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes, that one-liner is a good minimal example, it does give the same error with system perl on both 11.4 macs that I have available at the moment. I updated the question with it.

Comment: What output do you get when running the command `pkg-config --debug libxslt` ? [Here](https://pastebin.com/1SvqR8Nr) is the output I get.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I think I'm getting the exact same output  https://pastebin.com/WzCXatvN from the 'fresh' mac; the recently updated one (https://pastebin.com/X26QRx1v) has slightly different paths for the commandline tools SDK.

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same result as I get, very strange that the script works for me and not for you then.. I think I will have to update my mac to 11.4 to check more what is going on.

Comment: Added [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682584)

Answer (score 2):

### Perlbrew

Eventually, I succeeded with perlbrew instead of the default OS X system perl.

The following process worked, based on recommendations at https://perlbrew.pl :

```
curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash   
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
perlbrew install perl-5.16.0   
perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
sudo cpan -i XML::LibXSLT
```

I consider it not as a proper solution but as a workaround - after all, there's no reason why the OS X preinstalled libxslt shouldn't just work with the preinstalled system perl - but it at least works.

Comment: Great that you made it work. I will have a look at the issue with the system perl later. Note that you do not need to use (and should not use) `sudo` with the perlbrew perl. And perl version 5.16 is nine years old, I would have used one of the newest versions 5.34 or 5.32.

Comment: @HåkonHægland well, https://perlbrew.pl/ still lists 5.16 as "latest stable release" :)

Comment: Yes that is not good. Probably they just forgot to update that part. I will notify them.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cpan.org/src/) is a list of the stable releases

Comment: *"perlbrew.pl still lists 5.16 as latest stable release"* : Added a [comment](https://github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/issues/726) about this..